# How to properly install redis on opensuse Leap 42.3

Tags: linux, owncloud

I have a big problem. I new in Owncloud. I have installed a owncloud 10.0.3 (newest), but in administrator panel I have a few warnings. So im trying to fix these.

One of these are:

*transactional file locking should be configured to use memory-based locking, not the default slow database-based locking*

so, i read the manual of owncloud> 
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration/server/caching_configuration.html

Next, they say that I must install a redis module..so now I stand in front of wall..

Maybe I will write what I did till now. But i think the best way will be that someone shows me from the begining how to proprly install redis on opensuse.

Installed Redis by:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-4.0.2.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-4.0.2.tar.gz
cd redis-4.0.2
make
make install
```

add also php7-redis and extension=redis.so

Created file:
/etc/redis/redis.conf

```
supervised systemd
and then
dir /var/lib/redis
```

I have an entry Owncloud Configuration added:

```
This example config.php configuration uses Redis for the local server cache:

'memcache.local' => '\OC\Memcache\Redis',
'redis' => [
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => 6379,
],
'memcache.locking' => '\OC\Memcache\Redis', // Add this for best performance
```

Now I tried to change redis.service file, so i pasted in:

/etc/systemd/system/redis.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store    
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
User=redis
Group=redis
Environment=statedir=/run/redis
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/run/redis/redis.pid
ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /var/log/redis.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown redis:redis /var/log/redis.log
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p ${statedir}
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R redis:redis ${statedir}
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and error text from start redis serivice is:

```
linux-kye3:/srv/www/htdocs/owncloud # systemctl status redis.service
● redis.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; disabled; vendor     preset: disabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since 
śro 2017-10-04 11:09:57 CEST; 1s ago
Process: 13568 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 13564 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R redis:redis ${statedir} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 13560 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p ${statedir} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 13556 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown redis:redis /var/log/redis.log (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 13554 ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /var/log/redis.log (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 13275 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

paź 04 11:09:57 vesta systemd[1]: redis.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
paź 04 11:09:57 vesta systemd[1]: Failed to start redis.service.
paź 04 11:09:57 vesta systemd[1]: redis.service: Unit entered failed state.
paź 04 11:09:57 vesta systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result     'exit-code'.
```

Please somene smart to help.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a redis rpm for opensuse: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/leap/42.1/oss/x86_64/redis-3.0.4-6.1.x86_64.html . If that is not an option and docker is available I would recommend running redis in docker.

Comment: Your link is broken. I found the same but on ftp port cannot conect..firewall is disabled and no others forwards on 21.port..

Below I pasted a link which instruction I have made ealier and still not working.

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04